# The story of Lord Krishna's death

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhagavad-gita, avatars

I want to know the story of death of Lord Krishna. Please,somebody answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

When Yuddhisthir was made the King of Hastinapur; Duryodhan's mother Gandhari had cursed Lord Krishna. As Pandavas had defeated Kauravas because of Krishna's help.

She curses Krishna that **`one day he will be killed by a hunter and his Dwarka city will be destroyed`**.

Lord Krishna accepts the Gandhari's curse.

After Pandavas and their wife Draupadi's death, one day Lord Krishna was playing his flute during his trip to nearby forest...

There was a hunter named **Jara** who thought that Krishna who was playing his flute was a **rare bird**.

Jara fires a poisoned arrow Krishna's foot.

Krishna laments loudly due to pain, and the poison spreads in him.

Jara at once recognizes Krishna's voice and goes running towards him.

Jara profusely apologizes and cries...

To which Sri Krishna replies:

> I must go. My time has come.

*Answer without source citation.*

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: Hi, its wrong. Gandhari cursed Krishna that he and his kin will be destroyed but never mentioned how. Also, `After Pandavas and their wife Draupadi's death, one day Lord Krishna was playing his flute during his trip to nearby forest... ` - it was Krishna who died first, followed by Pandavas and Draupadi